# SUM data from other table when joining some tables with conditions

Tags: php, mysql, join, sum, left-join

I got a complicated question.

I have a query that combine data from several tables. for example:

```
traffic: id, traffic_source_id, first_hit_date
goals: id, goal_type, goal_date, goal_value
traffic_sources: id, source_name
```

goal_type could be "contact form", "demo download", "purchase"
goal_value is numeric. and display the number of times the user reach the goal on the same date (day).

I'm trying to show one row for each traffic_id, and then sum every goal for this traffic_id. When a user comes for the first time, he/she gets a traffic id that stays with him (cookie). he/she can reach a goal a week later after the first hit date, and then other goal 2 days later, for example.

I want to be able to query from date > to date and show the correct sum values of the goals for that speific range. 
When I try to use SUM(CASE WHEN ...) I can't sum just the range withing the goals table.

example:
**traffic**
from: 1-feb to 28-feb

```
3 | google adwords | 0 contact | 1 demo download | 1 purchase
4 | facebook       | 1 contact | 3 demo download | 3 purchase
```

but when I want to change the range from 1-feb to 14-feb

```
3 | google adwords | 0 contact | 1 demo download | 0 purchase
4 | facebook       | 0 contact | 2 demo download | 2 purchase
```

hope I'm clear enough...

any advice will be much appreciated.

---

Update:
query example of what I have now:

```
SELECT traffic.traffic_id as original_traffic_id hit_date, referrer, referrer_url, keyword, ip,
SUM(CASE goals.goal_type WHEN 'Contact' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) goal_contact,
SUM(CASE goals.goal_type WHEN 'Download' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) goal_download,
SUM(CASE goals.goal_type WHEN 'Signup' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) goal_signup,
SUM(CASE goals.goal_type WHEN 'Purchase' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) goal_purchase
FROM traffic
LEFT JOIN goals ON goals.traffic_id = traffic.traffic_id
WHERE traffic.traffic_id=100 AND hit_date >= '$from_date' AND hit_date <= '$to_date'
```

(where $from_date and $to_date are mysql date formats)

(this is not the real query since the original query much larger and includes about 7 more tables that joins in)
This query actually sums all the goals without having into cound goal_date. I want to be able to limit the SUM to the range of $from_date and $to_date

Hope it clears it a bit more.

Comment: Can you also show us the query that does the closest to what you want to achieve?

Comment: Can you please provide a few more samples of data from each table...  I'm not exactly seeing your how/where your traffic indicates the type of activity (contact, demo, purchase) from the given traffic site location... just the date of it.  How is "goal" applied... is it applied per traffic action, per site associated, or just based on the type... hence some sample data of traffic to help expand answers.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I've added some code that I hope will put some light into my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer for this yet, but I what I did is to summerize all goals with another query prior to the first one. 
The array looks like `$goals_array[traffic_id][goal_type] -> value`

And while looping through the main sql, just fetch the value from the $goals_array.
It works fast, and altough I wish to make this on one query, that's ok for now.

Comment: Why isn't there any relation between goals and traffic. If there is then problem will be solved easily